# How to implement operator-> for an iterator that constructs its values on-demand?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, operator-overloading

I have a C++ class that acts like a container:  it has `size()` and `operator[]` member functions.  The values stored "in" the container are `std::tuple` objects.  However, the container doesn't actually hold the tuples in memory; instead, it constructs them on-demand based on underlying data stored in a different form.

```
std::tuple<int, int, int>
MyContainer::operator[](std::size_t n) const {
    // Example: draw corresponding elements from parallel arrays
    return { underlying_data_a[n], underlying_data_b[n], underlying_data_c[n] };
}
```

Hence, the return type of `operator[]` is a temporary object, not a reference.  (This means it's not an lvalue, so the container is read-only; that's OK.)

Now I'm writing an iterator class that can be used to traverse the tuples in this container.  I'd like to model [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), which depends on [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), but InputIterator requires support for the expression `i->m` (where `i` is an iterator instance), and as far as I can tell, an `operator->` function is required to return a pointer.

Naturally, I can't return a pointer to a temporary tuple that's constructed on-demand.  One possibility that comes to mind is to put a tuple instance into the iterator as a member variable, and use it to store a copy of whichever value the iterator is currently positioned on:

```
class Iterator {
private:
    MyContainer *container;
    std::size_t current_index;

    // Copy of (*container)[current_index]
    std::tuple<int, int, int> current_value;
    // ...
};
```

However, updating the stored value will require the iterator to check whether its current index is less than the container's size, so that a past-the-end iterator doesn't cause undefined behavior by accessing past the end of the underlying arrays.  That adds (a small amount of) runtime overhead — not enough to make the solution impractical, of course, but it feels a little inelegant.  The iterator shouldn't really need to store anything but a pointer to the container it's iterating and the current position within it.

Is there a clean, well-established way to support `operator->` for iterator types that construct their values on-demand?  How would other developers do this sort of thing?

(Note that I don't really *need* to support `operator->` at all — I'm implementing the iterator mainly so that the container can be traversed with a C++11 "[range for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)" loop, and `std::tuple` doesn't have any members that one would typically want to access via `->` anyway.  But I'd like to model the iterator concepts properly nonetheless; it feels like I'm cutting corners otherwise.  Or should I just not bother?)

Comment: `operator->` doesn't have to return a pointer. It just has to return something on which `*` can be applied.

Comment: Hmm, so I could return a "fake pointer" that holds a value and returns that value when "dereferenced"?  I'm not sure whether that's more or less awkward than storing the value in the iterator itself.  :-)  But at least (with inlining) there'd be zero run-time overhead.

Comment: In any case, to model `ForwardIterator` you must meet this requirement: "If a and b are both dereferenceable, then a == b if and only if *a and *b are bound to the same object." That generally means iterators returning a proxy or containing the value within themselves can only be InputIterators

Comment: @KerrekSB, looks like the returned value actually has to support `->`, not `*`.  A fake-pointer class with its own `operator->` (that returns a real pointer) works, but implementing just `operator*()` in the fake pointer doesn't work.

Comment: [over.ref]/1: "An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()`
exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3)."

Comment: @Wyzard: Ah, yes, sorry. I said the wrong thing. You're right, the return value only has to support another indirection through `->` again, and this can be chained indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T>
struct pseudo_ptr {
  T t;
  T operator*()&&{return t;}
  T* operator->(){ return &t; }
};
```

then

```
struct bar { int x,y; };
struct bar_iterator:std::iterator< blah, blah >{
  // ...
  pseudo_ptr<bar> operator->() const { return {**this}; }
  // ...
};
```

This relies on how `->` works.

`ptr->b` for pointer `ptr` is simply `(*ptr).b`.

Otherwise it is defined as `(ptr.operator->())->b`.  This evaluates recursively if `operator->` does not return a pointer.

The `pseudo_ptr<T>` above gives you a wrapper around a copy of `T`.

Note, however, that lifetime extension doesn't really work.  The result is fragile.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example relying on the fact that `operator->` is applied repeatedly until a pointer is returned. We make `Iterator::operator->` return the Contained object as a temporary. This causes the compiler to reapply `operator->`. We then make `Contained::operator->` simply return a pointer to itself. Note that if we don't want to put `operator->` in the Contained on-the-fly object, we can wrap it in a helper object that returns a pointer to the internal Contained object.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

class Contained {
    public:
        Contained(int a_, int b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}
        const Contained *operator->() {
            return this;
        }
        const int a, b;
};

class MyContainer {
    public:
        class Iterator {
                friend class MyContainer;
            public:
                friend bool operator!=(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2) {
                    return it1.current_index != it2.current_index;
                }
            private:
                Iterator(const MyContainer *c, std::size_t ind) : container(c), current_index(ind) {}
            public:
                Iterator &operator++() {
                    ++current_index;
                    return *this;
                }
                // -> is reapplied, since this returns a non-pointer.
                Contained operator->() {
                    return Contained(container->underlying_data_a[current_index], container->underlying_data_b[current_index]);
                }
                Contained operator*() {
                    return Contained(container->underlying_data_a[current_index], container->underlying_data_b[current_index]);
                }
            private:
                const MyContainer *const container;
                std::size_t current_index;
        };
    public:
        MyContainer() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                underlying_data_a[i] = underlying_data_b[i] = i;
            }
        }
        Iterator begin() const {
            return Iterator(this, 0);
        }
        Iterator end() const {
            return Iterator(this, 10);
        }
    private:
        int underlying_data_a[10];
        int underlying_data_b[10];
};

int
main() {
    MyContainer c;

    for (const auto &e : c) {
        std::cout << e.a << ", " << e.b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, be careful: something like `const int &a = it->a;` would normally work, but won't here, as the temporary object will already be destroyed by the time `a` gets used.

Comment: Any particular reason for having `Contained` hold the individual values directly, as opposed to holding a `std::tuple` (and returning its address from `operator->`)?

Comment: @Wyzard: You could use a tuple, but then you'd have to wrap it, since std::tuple doesn't have -> overloaded for it.

Comment: But if the tuple is a member of `Contained `, you could just return the address of that member variable. `Contained ` *is* the wrapper. (Or am i missing something?)

Comment: @Wyzard: Yes, in which case `Contained` is the wrapper, though of course you would probably rename it.